# User input without newline?

Tags: c++

Basically I need user input for an integer, I tried these methods:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
 int PID;
 scanf("%i",&PID); //attempt 0
 cin >> PID; //attempt 1
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944861/getting-user-input-in-c

Comment: `_getch();` in visual studio. Warning this is **deprecated** and NOT recommended (`conio.h`)

Comment: C input streams are defined as being line-buffered, so you might not see any input until a newline has been sent.   If you want to read characters without the user pressing Enter you will have to use operating system-specific commands instead of Standard C. Maybe look at the `ncurses` library.

Answer (score 3):

Most command-line input methods require the user to press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to signal the end of the input, even if the app does not use the line break.

If you do not want the user to end the input with <kbd>ENTER</kbd> then you will likely have to resort to reading the input 1 character at a time and handle data conversions manually.  The problem is, without a line break, how do you know when the user has finished typing the input?  When the user has typed X number of characters/digits?  What if the user types fewer then your max?  Start a timer and stop reading when the user stops typing for X seconds?  See the problem?

Line breaks are not something to be ignored.  You should re-design your input logic to accept them, not avoid them.  If that is really not an option, then maybe you need to re-think why you are creating a command-line app in the first place instead of a GUI app where the user can press a button when ready.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot change the way my program works, because an integer is required for a PID and a newline is not helpful. Perhaps there is a way I can remove the newline? eg. foo.remove("\n");

Comment: You can use `cin >> PID` to read the integer, and then use `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')` to ignore any subsequent input after the integer up to and including the line break.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/